# How to escape multiple quotes in the query?

Tags: mysql, pdo, quotes

I have a query like this:

```
" SELECT IF(table.edited > 0, '<i title="c.edited"></i>','') AS edited, ... "
^                             ^         ^
```

The above query has a pdo-syntax-error ...! It is about **quote**. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes, same as any other string in PHP with quotes in it:

```
" SELECT IF(table.edited > 0, '<i title=\"c.edited\"></i>','') AS edited, ... "
```

Answer (score 1):

use PDO bindValue to insert clean string:

```
$query = "SELECT filename
           FROM Posters
           WHERE name = :name";
$statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
$statement->execute();
return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Well, this answer is kinda different than what I want ..! Because I want to use of the value of `c.edited` as `i` title.

Comment: `$yourvar = '<html>'.$your_php_value.'</html>';`
this is what php PDO was meant for, ease of value binding with tons of security against MYSQL injection, the `prepare($query)`. Escaping quotes in MYSQL works fine sure, but it will bite you very soon. Not to mention almost completely unreadable during maintenance or if you hand off the project to another DEV

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
" SELECT IF(table.edited > 0, CONCAT('<i title=\"', c.edited, '\"></i>','') AS edited, ..."
```

Using [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for combining both `c.edited` and a string.

Using `\` for escaping quote *(as @Aaron Mason mentioned in his answer)*